# Maven3 and M2eclipse mismatch when handling parent version?

Tags: maven, versioning, parent, m2eclipse

Does anyone know if M2Eclipse backed by maven3 supports parent definition without versions?

The maven3 specs says that it should be allowed, as per this [maven 3 beta overview](http://java.dzone.com/articles/maven-3-rides-town?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a+eclipsezone/frontpage+). However, M2Eclipse stills spits out a "*'parent.version' is missing*" error when the version tag is removed.

NB: I will qualify that I have a working build using other means. I'm posting this question because it would be nice to know if anyone has a versionless parent working with M2Eclipse; it's a much neater solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use m2e and not old m2eclipse.